# how can I show the pdf file content inside from razor file

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf, blazor-server-side

I created a document file from word and has exported as pdf . i want to show the pdf content  inside the Div element in razor page. How can I show the pdf content from razor page. Please can you provide an example code  how to show in blazor server side

Comment: Blazor is still running on the browser, in an HTML page that can use JavaScript. You can use the `object` or `embed` tag to display a PDF file from a URL that could easily be a Web API endpoint. If you want something fancier, you can use any of the JavaScript PDF viewer libraries, like `pdf.js`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos embed tag  requires install any assembly ?

Answer (score 7):

If you stored your pdf file directly in your documents for example in the folder wwwroot/pdf.
`wwwroot/pdf/test.pdf`

You can display this PDF with this line of html bellow :
`< embed src="pdf/test.pdf" style="width=100%; height=2100px;" />`
It will provide you a pdf displayer with printing options !

If you want to go further, upload your file and then display it, I will recommend you to go check this explanation :
https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2020/10/blazor-webassembly-fileupload.html 
The upload for PDF files works the same as Img file, you need to go check IBrowserFile documentation.
You will see that it has a Size obj and a OpenReadStream() function that will help you get the display Url for your file (image or pdf)

If the site abow closes, this is the upload code that is shown on it :

> ```
> @code{
>     List<string> imgUrls = new List<string>();
>     private async Task OnFileSelection(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
>     {
>         foreach (IBrowserFile imgFile in e.GetMultipleFiles(5))
>         {
>             var buffers = new byte[imgFile.Size];
>             await imgFile.OpenReadStream().ReadAsync(buffers);
>             string imageType = imgFile.ContentType;
>             string imgUrl = $"data:{imageType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(buffers)}";
>             imgUrls.Add(imgUrl);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This code was written by Naveen Bommidi, author of the blog where I found this usefull code

If you want, as I said, upload a PDF and then display it.
You can use the same html line :
`< embed src="@imgUrl" style="width=100%; height=2100px;" />`
And your uploaded files will be displaying.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slpPu.png)

Comment: embed from HTML5 ? not requires install any assembly ?

Comment: Yes @Kiquenet , embed from HTML5
Link for more information on the "embed" tag : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp

I didn't need any install, just added the line in my html and added my pdf file in the folder "wwwroot"

Comment: Just a reminder that you can also use base64 into the src attribute.
Like this: `<embed type="application/pdf" src="data:application/pdf;base64,{your string base64 byte array here}" />`